# How can I integrate BERT model in my notebook (Python)?

Tags: keras, text, architecture, classification

I am doing text classification with keras model (sequential). Now, what can I do to improve the model performance (the accuracy, the val accuracy, the prediction, etc).
This is my model architecture:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=train_padded.shape[1]))

model.add(Conv1D(48, 5, activation='relu', padding='valid'))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Another question please, can I insert Bert model for text classification in order to improve the val accuracy of my model?

Thank you !